# How to set viewing of Bookmarks User Profile tab to just the owner?

Tags: flags

So, with the Flag module comes a ready made flag and view for "Bookmarks". The view that comes with the Bookmark flag creates a tab on the user profile page labeled "Bookmarks" showing all of the bookmarks saved by that user.

I would like this tab to only be visible for the actual owner of that user profile page.

That way, if some other user views a different user's profile page, they will not see the Bookmarks tab.

Currently, from what I can tell, a view can only be limited in access by Roles or specific permissions. Any suggestions?

I would prefer now to have to use custom PHP.

Drupal 7.12

Answer (score 3):

Try "permissions" and "view own published content."

Answer (score 0):

I used the filter User:Current. So now I cannot see the bookmarks but I can still see the page.

If anybody has a better solution, pls post over here.

Here is a related link from drupal.org   https://www.drupal.org/node/605142